# Command-line to "deploy" ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, deployment, build-process

I am using Visual Studio Team Suites to develop a ASP.NET MVC project. I can deploy the web app to my dev machine using the "deploy" item from IS. Is there a command-line tool to do this task? What I am trying to do is to setup a continuous integration server (using TeamCity Pro), so that whenever I checkin new code, I will get a new build, deploy to a remote IIS server, and then run tests on the testing server.

Thanks,
-Yi

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Microsoft have such a deployment tool. Never used it myself.

Scott Hanselman has blogged about it [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MSDeployNewIISWebDeploymentTool.aspx)

Comment: Yes, MSDeploy would be a great way to go.

Answer (score 2):

MSDeploy, Microsoft's upcoming command-line deployment tool (which will be integrated into VS2010) is currently available in Beta2.

Info:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/346/web-deployment-tool/

Download (x86):
http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1602

Download (x64):
http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1603

Also, if you have disk access to the servers you want to deploy to from the CI server and don't need to install/remove things from the GAC or tweak the IIS metabase, plain old [robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) is a great option.

Comment: But how would you use Robocopy in this scenario? What I'm assuming the original post asked is how do you simulate what Visual Studio does with the Publish command but from the command line. In other words, how do you produce the same output that the Visual Studio Publish command produces (using publish method of "File System") from the command line?